# Where I can download MySQLSchemaProvider for Codesmith Generator?

Tags: mysql, code-generation, codesmith

I currently need to work with MYSQL so I wonder where I can download the latest version of MySQLSchemaProvider. I am using CodeSmith Generator version version: 5.3.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest MySQLSchemaProvider ships with CodeSmith Generator. You can see a list of the providers we ship with in the screenshot located [here](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/display/Generator/Debugging+a+Custom+Schema+Provider)